# Please help-- what object can I use to absorb static shock when getting out of my car?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

Whenever I get out of my car and touch the door, I get shocked. This has made me be afraid of going anywhere because I don't want to get shocked.

I already tried the penny, and I got shocked through the penny. What is a really strong object I can buy or find where I can just touch it to the door of my car and it will absorb the entire shock? Penny doesn't absorb the entire shock.

I also am not interested in preventing shock, I don't want to install anything in my car and I don't want to change shoes or anything. I just want a big object that I can touch to my car door so that it will absorb the shock for me. Something that actually works, as a penny doesn't absorb the entire shock. Please help! Please eliminate my fear of driving.

Comment: This is likely off-topic here. But, I usually use one of the all-metal keys on my keyring. It's long enough that you avoid the shock directly.

Comment: How do I know if a key is all metal? I still get shocked using my silver-colored car key.

Comment: I advise you to take your car to a mechanic. It is not customary for a car to give shocks like this. There must be some "internal hammerage" of the car.

Comment: I don't really have money to fix problems that aren't really necessary to be fixed, so I'm wondering if there's a big object that I can just buy or get somewhere that I can touch to my car and will eliminate the schock. I don't want to spend hundreds of dollars on this, but I'm willing to spend up to $30 on a 100% working object that does the job

Comment: A method I use is to place your finger on the metal while you are in the seat and leave it on as you get out. When your clothes rub on the seat, they become charged. The seat and your clothes, and you, form plates of 2 capacitors in series. While the plates are close, the charges attract each other, increasing the capacitance, making the voltage low. When you move away, the capacitance decreases, like a shrinking cylinder, increasing the pressure (voltage), which is coupled to you from your clothes. If you have your finger on the metal, the coupled charge just leaks away through your finger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resistor with value around 1 M$\Omega$ or a neon lamp.

Comment: Do I hold one end of the resistor while touching the car door with the other end? Or how do I hold it?

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your vehicle is building up a charge while you drive. What you need to do is to allow the charge in your car to flow to ground through something before *you* provide that path when you step out of the car. Rather than *absorbing* the shock, you need to allow it to pass to ground.

You can buy [a *static strip* (here is one from Canadian Tire)](http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/static-strap-with-reflective-strip-0375024p.html) for less than $20. It will mount under your car and drag on the ground.